# How to put a custom image over a formpanel tool

Tags: extjs4

The formpanel has the tools configuration, which I am using like this:

```
this.tools = [
        {
            id: "upload", 
            hidden: false,
            handler: function() {
                this.triggerUpload();
            }, 
            scope: this,
        },
]
```

Which works fine but I would like to have my own custom image in the little tool square, how do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this would have to be done in the CSS, look what the current CSS class for the image is and write your own that has the URL property set to your image.